# Como tratar um array com N linhas e transformar para uma lista para mandar para o C#

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, array

Estou mandando um array do *angular js* para o controller do *C#*, e estou tratando ele com *stringfy* para *json*.

Só que no meu método `POST` ele nao recebe nada, simplesmente retorna `null`

**Código C#**

```
 public void Post(string values)
    {
        var r = values;

    }
```

**Código Javascript**

```
    $scope.SubmitData = function (DataToSubmit) {
    var string = JSON.stringify(DataToSubmit);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            values: string,
        },
        url: 'api/aulamethod',
    });
}
```

Data que é inserida nos *inserts*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

dados que aparecem no `var string` depois do *stringfy*

```
 values:"[{"CompanyName":"column a","SupplierCode":"column b","DocumentNumber":"column c","Reference":"column d","InternalCurrencyValue":"column e","BlockadeUnblocking1":"column f","Justification":"column g","Request":"column h","$$hashKey":"object:23"}]"
```

Comment: Tenta assim: `data: { string }`

Comment: nao da :/ ja tentei

Comment: acredito que ele considere `aulamethod` como o nome do método no c#

Comment: No seu método Post troque a assinatura dele para (List<string> values).

Comment: sim eu alterei, mandei errado pq esqueci de alterar, ja coloquei aulamethod...
vou tentar netinho \m/

Comment: nao funcionou tbm

Comment: Qual é a versão do MVC da sua WebAPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu objetivo é postar esse valor como `String`, você deve primeiro garantir que está realizando o seu post com o type em `application/json`.

Crie uma ViewModel para refletir a estrutura que está postando:

```
public class ValuesViewModel
{
    public string Values { get; set; }
}
```

E na controller não esqueça de adicionar o `[FromBody]`

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]ValuesViewModel values)
{ 
   var r = values;       
}
```